# python timer for multi-thread

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, signals

Currently I meet this trouble:
I used a single thread script before, which is used to execute SQL one by one and for each SQL there is a time limitation -- 5400s. Therefore, if one of the SQL has run a long time more than 5400 sec, this SQL will be stopped and signed as 'time out'. The code of timer can be shown as:

```
def alarmrun(cmd_command):    
    try:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
        signal.alarm(5400)
        utils.system_output(cmd_command, retain_output=True)
        signal.alarm(0)
    except AssertionError:
        print "=======" + exec_nu + "alarm execute error======="
```

However, I need to make the SQL execute as multi-thread, which means that there are about 5 SQL running at the same time. As I recognized, the signal method does not support to be used in a child threading.

I start my threads in the parent thread as:

```
for i in range(len(threads)):
    threads[i].start()
```

Where can I use the signal to compute the time passed or, what others method can I try to reach the same effect in the multi-thread version?

Thank you!